# POST body undefined in Express 4

Tags: node.js, post, express

Im trying to post to a route in express 4, but when i try to log body i get undefined message, here are my configs:

**/server.js**

```
/* main module entry point */
'use strict';

var express    = require( './server/node_modules/express' );
var bodyParser = require( './server/node_modules/body-parser' );
var env        = require( './server/env' );
var app        = module.exports = express();

app.use( require( './server/modules/auth' ) );

app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/client/' ) );

app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( {
    extended: true
} ) );

app.use( bodyParser.json() );

app.get( '/*', function ( require, response ) {

    response.sendFile( __dirname + '/client/index.html' );

} );

app.listen( env.port, function () {

    console.log( 'Listening to port ' + env.port );

} );
```

**/server/modules/auth/index.js**

```
module.exports = (function () {

    var express = require('express'),
        router = express.Router(),
        signin = require('./signin.controller');

    router.route( '/signin' )
        .get( signin.get )
        .post( signin.post );

    return router;

})();
```

**/server/modules/auth/sigin.controller.js**

```
module.exports = (function () {

models = require( '../../database/models' );

function get( request, response ) {

    models.users.findAll().then( function ( users ) {

        response.json( users );

    } );
    console.log( 'Sign In' );

}

function post( request, response ) {

    console.log( 'Sign In ' + request.body );//Returns "Sign In Undefined"
    response.send('Signed In'+ request.body);

}

return {
    get: get,
    post: post
}

})();
```

Is there anything wrong in the code?, I'm using postman to test it:
[image: postman]

The header i'm using is:

*Content-Type: application/json*

Comment: Try removing your header.

Comment: Still same, undefined @BidhanA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order matters. Try this:

```
/* main module entry point */
'use strict';

var express    = require( './server/node_modules/express' );
var bodyParser = require( './server/node_modules/body-parser' );
var env        = require( './server/env' );
var app        = module.exports = express();

app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/client/' ) );

app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( {
    extended: true
} ) );

app.use( bodyParser.json() );

app.use( require( './server/modules/auth' ) );

app.get( '/*', function ( require, response ) {

    response.sendFile( __dirname + '/client/index.html' );

} );

app.listen( env.port, function () {

    console.log( 'Listening to port ' + env.port );

} );
```

Basically you're telling express not to parse the body content until after the middleware in auth.js is run.

Comment: Really thank you!, i didn't noticed it jaja, also i would like to know other thing, is it necessary to declare route params like `/any/route/:id` in order to send data, or could i just send them just as params?

Comment: You can also just send them as query string parameters if that's what you mean. So the user could call: `/any/route?id=123`

Comment: No no, what i mean is that Express support route params like: `/product/:id/detail`, but how is that different from sending them as above? check out [this link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/13/parameterized-routes-express-js/) to get an idea of what i say

Answer (score 1):

Starting from 4.16, feel free to use `express.json()` instead of `body-parse`, more detail: [express.json vs bodyParser.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232187/express-json-vs-bodyparser-json).