# express.json vs bodyParser.json

Tags: json, express

I'm writing a relatively new app and was wondering which I should use:

```
express.json()
```

or

```
bodyParser.json()
```

Can I assume they do the same thing.

I would like to just use `express.json()` as it is built in already.

Comment: express@4.17.1 just uses body-parser “1.19.0” as a dependency

Answer (score 413):

Earlier versions of Express used to have a lot of middleware bundled with it. bodyParser was one of the middleware that came with it. When Express 4.0 was released they decided to remove the bundled middleware from Express and make them separate packages instead. The syntax then changed from `app.use(express.json())` to `app.use(bodyParser.json())` after installing the bodyParser module.

bodyParser was added back to Express in release 4.16.0, because people wanted it bundled with Express like before. That means you don't have to use `bodyParser.json()` anymore if you are on the latest release. You can use `express.json()` instead.

The release history for 4.16.0 is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases/tag/4.16.0) for those who are interested, and the pull request is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/3423).

Comment: Can we also do `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` then?

Comment: Is that  means they do the same job?

Comment: what if i use both // Data Parsing
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false }));

is it good? because tutorial in youtube tells me to use both

Comment: @rickvian - You can use both if you want to. json is for JSON and urlencoded is for URL encoded data. If you add both you'll be able to parse both types.

Comment: It still amazes me that they thought it was a good idea to remove bodyParser in the first place!

Comment: For reference, the issue with discussion about adding the bodyParser back: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2211

Answer (score 26):

YES! Correct

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 18):

Yes both are same .

if you go into the file node_module/express/lib/express.js

you can see under module dependencies body parser module is already imported

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
//other modules
```

the objects and methods inside bodyparser module are accessible as they are exported using the special object module.exports

```
exports = module.exports = createApplication;
exports.json = bodyParser.json
```

this is accessible from express object just by calling

```
express.json()
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes!! you can use both of them. However, since `express.json()` is now already built into `express`, it is wiser to use `express.json()` than the `bodyParser.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! Due to the widespread opinion of the people to integrate body-parser back with the express, the latest release does exactly this. You should be right to assume that both perform the same tasks, that is to recognize incoming request object as JSON objects. Feel free to use either.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Express (Express 4.16.0 and later), the express.json() middleware is built-in and replaces the need for the external body-parser package. Therefore, you should use express.json() to parse JSON data in your Express application.

Prior to Express 4.16.0, body-parser was a separate package that was commonly used to parse request bodies, including JSON. However, Express now includes the express.json() middleware as part of its core, providing the same functionality as body-parser.

Therefore, in your case, express.json() is the recommended choice as it provides the same functionality as body-parser.json() and eliminates the need for an additional dependency in your project.