# Express: PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, base64, tedious

I'm getting this error when I try to send a Base64 string in a POST request.

```
POST /saveImage 413 10.564 ms - 1459
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
```

Already tried

```
-->  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }))
-->  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));
-->  app.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));
```

Here's my code **(api.js class)**

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const router = express.Router();
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection
var Request = require('tedious').Request
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES
var multer = require('multer');
 ....
 ....
 ....



router.post('/saveImage', (req, res) => {
request=new Request('SAVE_IMAGE',(err, rowCount, rows)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }

});
request.addParameter("Base64Image", TYPES.Text, req.body.IMG)
connection.callProcedure(request);
 });
```

**API CALL** (Image class contains a Base64 format image and other fields, but I guess the problem occurs because of the Base64 string length. Small images don't cause any trouble)

```
create(image: Image) {
return this._http.post('/saveImage', image)
  .map(data => data.json()).toPromise()
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use `express` instead of `body-parser`, as `body-parser` got merged back in `express` a long ago.

I am using this code and it seems to work fine, setting the `limit` option to 200mb, of both `express.json` and `express.urlencoded`

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: "200mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "200mb" }));
```

Source: [express.json vs bodyparser.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232187/express-json-vs-bodyparser-json)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error. I tried what you tried it did not work.

I guess you are uploading a file. The simple way to solve this is to not set a Content-Type.

my problem was that I was setting on my headers: `Content-Type: application/json` and I am [was] using multer (expressjs middle for uploading files).

I have the error whenever I try uploading a file.

So when using postman or making such requests using any tools or libraries like axiosjs or fetch() API do not set content-type.

Once you remove the Content-type it will work. That is what I did

on my code, I have:

```
const express = require('express');

...

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
...
```

...And it is working because I removed Content-Type on my postman headers.

Make sure you are not using Content-Type on the headers.