# Nodejs form submit using express returns undefined value

Tags: node.js, express

Basically, this simple form submit does not return anything. Using postman, I can only get the request.body data, or undefined (console.log) / {} for the input name. On form submit nothing happens at all. I've read all the body-parser solutions, but it is my understanding that this now taken care of by express 4.

here is my form (home.ejs):

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
</div>
<button type="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is my server code:

```
//Load packages
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//SERVER
// Listen to the App Engine-specified port, or 8080 otherwise
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
})

//render home page
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render("home");
});


//post request
app.post('/', function(req, res)
{var body = res.json(req.body)
 var name = body.name; 
    console.log(name);
});
```

Comment: type="button" type="submit" - maybe you should delete type="button" ? have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

run "npm i body-parser" in your CLI and import body-parser like

`const bodyParser = require('body-parser')`

and then use the middleware

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

also you should update the post request handler

```
//post request
app.post('/', function(req, res)
    {var name = req.body.name; 
    console.log(name);
    res.status(201).send();
});
```

Comment: This would cause the request to hang, as the response is never sent ...

Comment: Thanks! This worked (left out Bodyparser as this is native to Express 4); Not sure why I missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `express.urlencoded` or `bodyParser.urlencoded` both are same [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232187/express-json-vs-bodyparser-json/49459134.)
The thing you need to change here is there are two button type so add only one

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Submit</button>
```

and replace with this code

```
//post request
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var name = req.body.name
    res.json(name);
    //res.send(name);
    console.log(name)
});
```

Comment: Please make sure that in `Postman`  go to `body` ->  `x-www-form-urlencoded` and add `key-values` pairs  there

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick! Really appreciated it.