# why my fetch post is not working it is not responding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, nedb

```
addwordform.addEventListener('submit', (event)=>{
  event.preventDefault();
    const formdata=new FormData(addwordform);
    const word=formdata.get('addword');
    const description =formdata.get('addiscription');
    const worddata={
        word,description,totalcount
    };
  console.log(worddata);
  fetch(API_URL,{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
          'content-Type':'application/json'
      },
      body:JSON.stringify(worddata),
  }).then(response=>response.json()).then( data =>{
     console.log(data);
       });
});
```

this is the client side javascript 
here API_URL="http://localhost:3005/word"
and server side code is

```
const express= require('express');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const datastore=  require('nedb');
const app= express();
app.listen(3005,()=>{console.log("listening on :http://localhost:3005")});
app.use(serveStatic('public',{'index':['client.html']}));
const database=new datastore('database.db');
database.loadDatabase();
app.post('/word',(req,res)=>{
   const data=req.body;
   database.insert(data);
   res.json();
});
```

i am using express a node framework and vanilla javascript for client side all i want is to post the data  from a form that has an id=addwordform and i am using nedb a light weight database management in node 
.problem with it is the worddata that i am sending from client side is not getting in the server side "req" so i cant save it in database and ultimatly i cant "res" it back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using express version >= `4.16`. Body parser comes bundled with express.

It parses incoming requests with JSON payloads and is based on body-parser.

It is not needed to use `body-parser`. [Here is the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

You just have to add this code before require your routes.

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Here is the [stackoverflow original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232187/express-json-vs-bodyparser-json/47232318#47232318).

Here is the [express release](https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases/tag/4.16.0)

Here is the [express commit](https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/3423)