# Fetch() data is not showing up on the server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am sending a simple fetch() to my server as follows:

```
eo.put = function (state) {
  
  console.log('PUT:state', state);

  let _id = encodeURIComponent(state._id);
  const options = { 
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
    method: 'PUT', 
    body: JSON.stringify(state)
  };
  fetch("/articles/put/" + _id, options )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('RESPONSE', response);
      // you need to update the DOM here
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("DEBUG: fetch/PUT error", error);
    });
}
```

and I can verify that state is populated with the console.log().

However; on the server side req.body is not populated and shows undefined.

```
// .. snip
app.use('/articles', routes.articles);
// .. snip

// UPDATE OPERATIONS
router.route('/put/:_id').put((req, res) => {
  const _id = req.params._id;
  const obj = req.body;
  

      /*
      **
      ** req.body is empty
      **
      */
      debug && console.log('DEBUG: route: /articles/put : req.body', req.body);
    
      DBM.updateArticle(_id, obj).then(() => {
      }).catch((err)=>{
        res.status(500).send("DEBUG: database internal error", err);
      });
      res.end();
    });
```

Comment: the URLs don't seem to match.

Comment: also you need the JSON express plugin.

Comment: The URLs match ... I have verified the route is being hit on the server ... you just can't see the `/articles` in the code I have up there.  What do you mean by JSON express plugin?

Comment: I added in the app.use command above ... Express can handle JSON without a plugin I believe.

Comment: app.use(express.json()); ... I had commented this command out and that was breaking the body ... it is called built in middleware ... thanks for pointing me in the right direction ...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to add a [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// your routes...
```

Comment: It's pretty odd but they have gone back and forth on to wether or not you need to install it separately ... I do not as I am using the latest version of Express ... see here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232187/express-json-vs-bodyparser-json/47232318

Comment: @jonjonbonbon Thanks, I didn't know. In the end , what was your problem ?

Comment: I had forgot to include `app.use(express.json)` ... very odd statement ... probably why I forgot ... if it can parse JSON ... just parse it ... but you have to tell it to.